# remove 00:00:00 from 2015-05-14 00:00:00 string jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this string

```
2015-05-14 00:00:00
```

and what I want is to remove the "00:00:00" and leaves "2015-05-14", so basically the string after trim will be only "2015-05-14". Any ideas how to make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to spilt the string using space and take the first one.

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

```
"2015-05-14 00:00:00".split(' ')[0];
```

```js
var a = "2015-05-14 00:00:00".split(' ')[0];
alert(a);
```

OR, You can use `.replace()`

```
"2015-05-14 00:00:00".replace('00:00:00', '').trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery does not have functionality to handle date time functionality.

If you need javascript to handle date time then you should resort to something like moment.js

it a javascript library you can download it from here http://momentjs.com/