# How to remove ending 00:00:00 in timestamp in a series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to graph coronavirus cases over time, but my timestamps are being weird. I want to remove the 00:00:00 at the end of the timestamp. How can I do this?

the index of the series I am plotting:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-01', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04',
               '2020-03-05', '2020-03-06', '2020-03-07', '2020-03-08',
               '2020-03-09', '2020-03-10',
               ...
               '2020-07-09', '2020-07-10', '2020-07-11', '2020-07-12',
               '2020-07-13', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-15', '2020-07-16',
               '2020-07-17', '2020-07-18'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=140, freq=None)
```

code:

```
plt.figure()
totalconfirm['Cases'].plot(kind='bar', rot=15, title="Cases per Day in all Michigan Counties", color='r', label = 'Confirmed')
totalprob['Cases'].plot(kind = 'bar', rot=15, bottom=totalconfirm['Cases'], color = 'b', label = 'Probable')
#totalconfirm['Deaths'].plot(color = 'black', label = 'Deaths')

ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10)) 
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter( mdates.DateFormatter("%b %d", tz=None) )
plt.show()
```

[image]

after the new code:
[image]

Have looked at [remove 00:00:00 from 2015-05-14 00:00:00 string jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520914/remove-000000-from-2015-05-14-000000-string-jquery) and [Remove "days 00:00:00"from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059278/remove-days-000000from-dataframe) but both didn't work/gave me errors.

Comment: You haven't shared your code but take a look at [Matplotlib's Date Formatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works to  remove 00:00:00 from the dates (`df.index.format()`)
Also, you can create your DatetimeIndex using pandas in a more simplified way.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#Create the DatetieIndex auto
df = pd.DataFrame( index= pd.date_range(start="2020-03-01",end="2020-07-18"))
#for y value only
df['cases'] = np.arange(140)


ax = df.plot( kind='bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.format(), rotation='vertical', size=6)
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=30)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, just I can't see all of the dates on the axis, but using rot=15 isn't working. How can I fix that?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! Since that is directly setting the axis to the bar plot how would I plot the probable dataset on top of the confirmed set?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured that out as well. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I set the maximum dates on x axis to be '30' with plt.locator_params. Just delete that and all the dates will appear again.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your column as date before plotting:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date
```